# Several views in my Ruby on Rails app requires me to refresh the page before it works properly, a search and the Google Maps especially

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sprockets, webpacker

I converted a program called CtrlPanel from Ruby v2.2.2 & Rails v4.2.1 to Ruby 2.7.3 & Rails 6.1.3.2 and I have it working pretty well now for the most part (was NOT an easy process for me at all).  I have even added a search to one of the cross reference pages.  However I have had a small bug for a while I have just not had any luck in tracking down.

I thought originally it was my search but then when I started looking more closely I noticed I was having this same symptom in other parts of the program.  What happens is if you go to the Dealership Map page which uses the Google MAPS API, it will only partially load the fist time and you have to hit the refresh on your browser and then it works perfectly.  I have the very same behavior on my search.  I only have about 2 1/2 months or so real world experience with Ruby on Rails so I thought it was originally something I was doing wrong but now that I see it is happening on other parts of the code I figured out after trying to re-code my search about 100 different ways it has nothing to do with it at all.

I have seen MANY posts from people having very similar issues but I never seem to find a solution and there is usually never an indication it is solved.  I am assuming this has to do with the fact it was originally written on the older versions of Ruby on Rails and there is probably something legacy that is causing this behavior.  I have just been unable to find it.  I have tried the following so far:

Removed turbolinks & jquery-turbolinks gems and all turbolinks references ( I saw some posts saying this was an issue with Turbolinks )
I tried moving all of the JavaScript out of the Sprockets or the older JS sub system in Rails from the APP/ASSETS/JAVASCRIPT into the APP/JAVASCRIPT folder so Web Packer could compline everything (was a bit faster but did not solve the issue).  Along this same idea I even removed the old application.js file that used the older method of specifying the JS libraries you want to use, no luck.  Faster for sure, but didn't stop the issue with having to refresh the page for some of the views to work right.

I am really not even sure WHAT to post on here to show anyone because the possibilities are so broad maybe if someone has a theory you can let me know what you would like me to post up here and I will be happy to share it.  It's hard to me to imagine this is not something more fundamental that I just don't understand with Ruby on Rails.  It is using older Bootstrap v2.3.2, older Jquery and popper.js and they all seem to be working, drop down menus working, everything works, other than this strange need to refresh the page to get the dealership map to work or my search to work.  The first time you go to my search if you click on my search button or hit enter, it does nothing.  It's almost like in Java when a thread becomes frozen?  That is the best way I can describe it.  You refresh the page, and it works perfectly.

If anyone has any idea and if anyone wants me to post something let me know what you would like to see and I will post it.  Otherwise since I have no idea where this problem is coming from I would have to almost post the entire program up as I can't figure out what is causing this.  OH It does the same thing in Production on Heroku as it does on Development on my laptop or Production on my laptop, so it doesn't seem to care which environment it is in.

Any ideas would be GREATLY appreciated.

Here is application.htlm.haml

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title= full_title(yield(:title))
    %meta{:content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", :name => "viewport"}
    %script{:src => "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"}
    %script{:crossorigin => "anonymous", :integrity => "sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG", :src => "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"} 
    %link{:href => "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css", :rel => "stylesheet"}/
    %script{:src => "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"}
    %script{:src => "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gmaps4rails/2.1.2/gmaps4rails.js"} :cdata
    %script{:src => "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"} :cdata
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all"
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css"
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css"
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "print", media: "print"
    = javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDOejvFkvPN_KP_9gnjH-Z8PB4eLtdju4E&libraries=geometry"
    = javascript_pack_tag     "application"
    = javascript_include_tag "https://www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick"
    = javascript_include_tag "https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = csp_meta_tag
    = render 'layouts/shim'
   

  %body
    = render 'layouts/header'
    .container-fluid.round.master
      - flash.each do |key, value|
        .alert-container
          .span6.offset3.alert-message.center{:class => "alert alert-#{key}"}
            = value
            %button.close#close-alert{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} ×
      = yield
      .spacer{style: "width:100%;margin-bottom:80px;"}
      = render 'layouts/footer'
```

Here is the Cross's view:
You will see I tried putting the search and piggy backing off of the index action and the last thing I tried was giving it its own method and it worked exactly the same regardless of what method I used.  It is so confusing to me why a refresh would cause it to work?!?

```
%h1 Crosses
.row-fluid
  .span10.offset1
    %table.table.table-striped.data-table.data-table-column-search
      %thead
        = form_tag('/crosses/search', method: "get",  class: "navbar-search") do
          = text_field_tag :q, nil, placeholder: "Search Crosses", class: "search-query"
          %button.btn{:type => "submit"} Search Crosses:
        %tr
          %th{ data: { priority: "2" } } Make
          %th{ data: { priority: "3" } } Model
          %th{ data: { priority: "1" } } All Catalysts
          %th{ data: { priority: "4" } } Redline
          %th{ data: { priority: "5" } } Roadwarrior
          %th{ data: { priority: "6" } } Skyline
          %th{ data: { priority: "7" } } OE Gasket
          %th{ data: { priority: "8" } } Redline IN Gasket
          %th{ data: { priority: "9" } } Redline OUT Gasket
          %th{ data: { priority: "10" } } OE Clamp
          %th{ data: { priority: "11" } } Redline IN Clamp
          %th{ data: { priority: "12" } } Redline OUT Clamp
          %th.none Durafit
          %th.none Durafit Gasket
          %th.none Description
          %th.none Position
          %th.none Start Year
          %th.none End Year
          %th.none OE CAC #
          %th.none Redline CAC #
          %th.none OE Outlet Gasket #
          %th.none Redline Outlet Gasket #
          %th.none Redline DOC
          - if can?(:update, Cross) || can?(:destroy, Cross)
            %th.none
      %tbody
        - @crosses.each do |cross|
          %tr

            %td= cross.make
            %td= cross.model
            %td= cross.all_reference_numbers
            %td= cross.redline_dpf_number
            %td= cross.roadwarrior_name
            %td= cross.skyline_name
            %td= cross.oe_gasket_number
            %td= cross.redline_gasket_number
            %td= cross.redline_outlet_gasket_number
            %td= cross.clamp_part_number
            %td= cross.redline_clamp_part_number
            %td= cross.redline_outlet_clamp_number
            %td= cross.cdti_name
            %td= cross.cdti_gasket_number
            %td= cross.description
            %td= cross.position
            %td= cross.start_year
            %td= cross.end_year
            %td= cross.oe_cac_number
            %td= cross.redline_cac_number
            %td= cross.outlet_gasket
            %td= cross.redline_outlet_gasket_number
            %td= cross.redline_doc_number
            - if can?(:update, cross) || can?(:destroy, cross)
              %td
                - if can?(:update, cross)
                  = link_to 'Edit', edit_cross_path(cross), class: 'btn btn-warning'
                - if can?(:destroy, cross)
                  = link_to 'Delete', cross, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger'

      %tfoot
        %tr
          %th{ data: { priority: "2" } } Make
          %th{ data: { priority: "3" } } Model
          %th{ data: { priority: "1" } } All Catalysts
          %th{ data: { priority: "4" } } Redline
          %th{ data: { priority: "5" } } Roadwarrior
          %th{ data: { priority: "6" } } Skyline
          %th{ data: { priority: "7" } } OE Gasket
          %th{ data: { priority: "8" } } Redline IN Gasket
          %th{ data: { priority: "9" } } Redline OUT Gasket
          %th{ data: { priority: "10" } } OE Clamp
          %th{ data: { priority: "11" } } Redline IN Clamp
          %th{ data: { priority: "12" } } Redline OUT Clamp
          %th.none Durafit
          %th.none Durafit Gasket
          %th.none Description
          %th.none Position
          %th.none Start Year
          %th.none End Year
          %th.none OE CAC #
          %th.none Redline CAC #
          %th.none OE Outlet Gasket #
          %th.none Redline Outlet Gasket #
          %th.none Redline DOC
          - if can?(:update, Cross) || can?(:destroy, Cross)
            %th.none
    %br/
    = link_to 'New Cross', new_cross_path, class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Here is the Cross's controller:

```
class CrossesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cross, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  load_and_authorize_resource
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:index_public]
  skip_authorization_check :only => :index_public
  skip_authorize_resource :only => :index_public

  def index
    @crosses = Cross.order(:id).all
    
#    if params[:q] && !params[:q].empty?
#      @crosses = @crosses.search(params[:q].downcase)  #Search through the collection we already had 
#    end    

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render inline: force_get ? "window.location.href = window.location.href;" : "location.reload();" }
      format.html {}
      format.csv {
        send_data Cross.to_csv, filename: "crosses-#{ Date.today }.csv"
      }

    end
  end
  

  def search
    if params[:q].blank?
      @crosses = Cross.order(:id).all
    else
      @crosses = Cross.search(params[:q].downcase)
    end
  end

  def index_public
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'

    response = {  }

    case params[:resource]
    when 'redline_gaskets'
      # response[:data] = Cross.redline_gaskets.order(:redline_gasket_number).pluck( :oe_gasket_number, :application_description, :redline_gasket_number, :redline_clamp_part_number, :cdti_name )
      response[:data] = Cross.redline_gaskets.order(:redline_gasket_number).pluck( :primary_catalyst_number, :all_reference_numbers, :redline_gasket_number, :oe_gasket_number, :make, :model, :redline_clamp_part_number )
    when 'redline_clamps'
      # response[:data] = Cross.redline_clamps.order(:redline_clamp_part_number).pluck( :redline_clamp_part_number, :application_description, :all_reference_numbers, :redline_gasket_number )
      response[:data] = Cross.redline_clamps.order(:redline_clamp_part_number).pluck( :primary_catalyst_number, :all_reference_numbers, :redline_clamp_part_number, :clamp_part_number, :make, :model, :redline_gasket_number )
    when 'redline_dpfs'
      # response[:data] = Cross.redline_dpfs.order(:redline_dpf_number).pluck( :redline_dpf_number, :year, :application_description, :all_reference_numbers )
      response[:data] = Cross.redline_dpfs.order(:redline_dpf_number).pluck( :primary_catalyst_number, :all_reference_numbers, :redline_dpf_number, :make, :model, :redline_cac_number, :redline_gasket_number, :redline_outlet_gasket_number, :redline_clamp_part_number, :redline_outlet_clamp_number )
    when 'all'
      response[:data] = Cross.order(:redline_dpf_number).pluck( :primary_catalyst_number, :make, :model, :cdti_name, :redline_dpf_number, :skyline_name, :roadwarrior_name, :redline_cac_number, :oe_gasket_number, :redline_gasket_number, :redline_outlet_gasket_number, :clamp_part_number, :redline_clamp_part_number, :redline_outlet_clamp_number, :all_reference_numbers  )
    end

    render json: { content_type: 'application/json',
           status: 200,
           text: response.as_json }
    end
 

  # GET /crosses/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /crosses/new
  def new
    @cross = Cross.new
  end

  # GET /crosses/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /crosses
  def create
    @cross = Cross.new(cross_params)

    if @cross.save
      redirect_to crosses_url, notice: 'Cross was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /crosses/1
  def update
    if @cross.update(cross_params)
      redirect_to crosses_url, notice: 'Cross was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  # DELETE /crosses/1
  def destroy
    @cross.destroy
    redirect_to crosses_url, notice: 'Cross was successfully removed.'
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_cross
      @cross = Cross.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def cross_params
      params.require(:cross).permit(
        :cost, :price, :cdti_name, :roadwarrior_name, :skyline_name,
        :application_description, :make, :all_reference_numbers,
        :cdti_gasket_number, :oe_gasket_number, :redline_gasket_number,
        :outlet_gasket, :outlet_gasket_quantity,
        :clamp_part_number, :redline_clamp_part_number, :redline_dpf_number,
        :redline_doc_number, :redline_car_number, :redline_egr_number,
        :redline_cac_number, :year, :liter, :fuel, :inlet_description,
        :outlet_description, :length, :description, :position, :start_year,
        :end_year, :model, :oe_cac_number, :redline_outlet_gasket_number,
        :redline_outlet_clamp_number
      )
    end
end
```

Comment: A small  example of the controller and view code would be a good start.

Comment: @dbugger  I added the application.html.haml, the crosses index.html.haml and the cross's controller.  If there is anything else you want to see please let me know.  I logically just can't think of why the code would work only after a refresh.

Comment: Don't need both `before_action :set_cross, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`
and `load_and_authorize_resource`.  Might be stepping on yourself. Also looking at all the goodies you are loading in your header might be that somethings don't have time to load correctly or there's a conflict somewhere.  I'd start by creating a simple view and adding things back in one by one.